# Button/interface of different terminals changed on Visual Studios Code, how do i change it back to default interface?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I was exploring around with Visual Studio Code, the interface/button of the changing terminal seemed to changed to his look. How do I revert it back to old look?

The new interface:

[image: The new interface]

->>>

Default interface:

[image: Default interface]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `settings.json` file and remove the below code to make it back to default

```
"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true
```

Or Go to File > Preferences > Settings > search `@feature:terminal` in your settings file and uncheck below Terminal.Integrated.Tabs.Enabled

[image]

NOTE: Just incase future, If you play more around your VSCode settings, You can just open ur `settings.json` file and press Ctrl+Z to revert the latest changes. (Condition: VSCode isn't closed after making changes)

Comment: You can accept the answer is it helped. It will help others to identify.